# Google web app server returns null even though logger.log confirms theirs data

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a google web app that checks to see if the a value (predefined from dropdown list so it will always been in the column") is in a column, if it is, it returns information about that value. however i am trying to update it so if the value is not found in the column(user entered value), it searches a second column to see if anyone has entered that value before. the issue i am having is once it finds the user entered value, it collects the value of the cells adjacent to it and flicks it back to the client side HTML javascript, the client side is seeing it as null. It's currently working fine for the first section which uses the predefined drop down choices. it's still finding the correct information, its just the client side for some reason cannot see it. I am abit of a novice when it comes to coding so any help anyone could provide would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
    function sendFleet(e){ // This code sends the dropdown value to the server side
  e.preventDefault();
  var fleet = document.getElementById("Fleet").value
  document.getElementById('photostatus').innerHTML = "Waiting For Photo.."
  if(fleet != "Not on this list?"){
  var data1 = {
    FleetNumber: document.getElementById("Fleet").value,
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(consoleyay)
  .sendFleet(data1)

  }
  else if(fleet == "Not on this list?"){
  console.log("right area")
  document.getElementById("Rego").innerHTML= "Rego"
  document.getElementById("NOLF").style.display=""
  document.getElementById("NOLR").style.display=""
  document.getElementById("NOLB").style.display=""
  document.getElementById("NOLS").style.display=""
  document.getElementById("Fleet").style.display="none"
  document.getElementById("Rego").style.display="none"    
  }
  }
   function SENDFLEET(e){ // This code sends a user entered value to the server.
  e.preventDefault();
  var fleet = document.getElementById("NOLF").value
  document.getElementById('photostatus').innerHTML = "Waiting For Photo.."
  var data1 = {
    FleetNumber: document.getElementById("NOLF").value,
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(consoleyay)
  .sendFleet(data1)
  }   

function sendFleet(data1){
var Fleet = data1.FleetNumber
var FleetListing = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ufyN6mgzdHXoYbVC6TENcc7V2zGxdQtp0ctaCR-kiEw").getSheetByName("FleetListing")
var data2 = FleetListing.getRange(3,3,FleetListing.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reduce(function (a, b) { //flatten the 2D array obtained by .getValues()
return a.concat(b);
});;
var fleetdata = FleetListing.getRange(3,1,FleetListing.getLastRow(),8).getValues()
var Search1 = data2.indexOf(Fleet)
var site = ""
var type = ""
var fleet = ""
var rego = ""
var insidev = ""
var outsidev = ""
var insideb = ""
var outsideb = ""
var search = ""
Logger.log(Search1)
if(Search1 != "-1"){
Logger.log("shouldn't be here")
site = fleetdata[Search1][0]
type = fleetdata[Search1][1]
fleet = fleetdata[Search1][2]
rego = fleetdata[Search1][3]
insidev = fleetdata[Search1][4]
outsidev = fleetdata[Search1][5]
insideb = fleetdata[Search1][6]
outsideb = fleetdata[Search1][7]
search = Search1
}
else if(Search1 == "-1"){
var MTL = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ufyN6mgzdHXoYbVC6TENcc7V2zGxdQtp0ctaCR-kiEw").getSheetByName("MasterToLocal")
var data3 = MTL.getRange(1,3,MTL.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reduce(function (c, d) { //flatten the 2D array obtained by .getValues()
return c.concat(d);
});; 
var fleetdata1 = MTL.getRange(1,1,MTL.getLastRow(),8).getValues()
var Search2 = data3.indexOf(Fleet)
Logger.log("lukes okay")
Logger.log(Fleet)
Logger.log(Search2)
Logger.log(data3)
if(Search2 != "-1"){
  Logger.log("Test start")
  site = fleetdata1[Search2][0]
  Logger.log(site)
  type = fleetdata1[Search2][1]

  fleet = fleetdata1[Search2][2]

  rego = fleetdata1[Search2][3]

  insidev = fleetdata1[Search2][4]

  outsidev = fleetdata1[Search2][5]

  insideb = fleetdata1[Search2][6]

  outsideb = fleetdata1[Search2][7]
  search = Search2
  Logger.log("Test Finish")
  }
}
return [site,type,fleet,rego,insidev,outsidev,insideb,outsideb,search]
}

function consoleyay(details){ // this is the code that handles the response from the server.
console.log(details)
var site = document.getElementById("Site").value
console.log(site)
console.log("issues 1")
var Type = document.getElementById("Type").value
console.log("issue 2")
var fleet = details[2]
var rego = details[3]
var inv = details[4]
var outv = details[5]
console.log("before bg")
var inb = details[6]
var outb = details[7]
console.log("after BG")
var Search1 = details[8]
```

Comment: Per documentation only certain values are allowed to be sent over the wire: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values As you discovered, a `Date` must first be changed to a numeric or string representation, via either `getTime` or `toString`. I prefer `getTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Instead of using .getValue, i used .getDisplayValue which will return the date as a string.